# Run filebeat on windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I 'm trying to run filebeat on windows 10 and send to data to elasticsearch and kibana all on localhost. This is my config file filebeat.yml

```
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The filebeat.reference.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/index.html

# For more available modules and options, please see the filebeat.reference.yml sample
# configuration file.

# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    # - /var/log/*.log
    - D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\logs
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ['^DBG']

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ['^ERR', '^WARN']

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #exclude_files: ['.gz$']

  # Optional additional fields. These fields can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1

  ### Multiline options

  # Multiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  #multiline.pattern: ^\[

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  #multiline.negate: false

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  #multiline.match: after

# filestream is an input for collecting log messages from files. It is going to replace log input in the future.
- type: filestream

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: false

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    # - /var/log/*.log
    - D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\logs
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ['^DBG']

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ['^ERR', '^WARN']

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #prospector.scanner.exclude_files: ['.gz$']

  # Optional additional fields. These fields can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1

# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  #reload.period: 10s

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


# ================================== General ===================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

# ================================= Dashboards =================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here or by using the `setup` command.
#setup.dashboards.enabled: false

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  #host: "localhost:5601"

  # Kibana Space ID
  # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
  # the Default Space will be used.
  #space.id:

# =============================== Elastic Cloud ================================

# These settings simplify using Filebeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
#cloud.id:

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
#cloud.auth:

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  #protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~

# ================================== Logging ===================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publisher", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]

# ============================= X-Pack Monitoring ==============================
# Filebeat can export internal metrics to a central Elasticsearch monitoring
# cluster.  This requires xpack monitoring to be enabled in Elasticsearch.  The
# reporting is disabled by default.

# Set to true to enable the monitoring reporter.
#monitoring.enabled: false

# Sets the UUID of the Elasticsearch cluster under which monitoring data for this
# Filebeat instance will appear in the Stack Monitoring UI. If output.elasticsearch
# is enabled, the UUID is derived from the Elasticsearch cluster referenced by output.elasticsearch.
#monitoring.cluster_uuid:

# Uncomment to send the metrics to Elasticsearch. Most settings from the
# Elasticsearch output are accepted here as well.
# Note that the settings should point to your Elasticsearch *monitoring* cluster.
# Any setting that is not set is automatically inherited from the Elasticsearch
# output configuration, so if you have the Elasticsearch output configured such
# that it is pointing to your Elasticsearch monitoring cluster, you can simply
# uncomment the following line.
#monitoring.elasticsearch:

# ============================== Instrumentation ===============================

# Instrumentation support for the filebeat.
#instrumentation:
    # Set to true to enable instrumentation of filebeat.
    #enabled: false

    # Environment in which filebeat is running on (eg: staging, production, etc.)
    #environment: ""

    # APM Server hosts to report instrumentation results to.
    #hosts:
    #  - http://localhost:8200

    # API Key for the APM Server(s).
    # If api_key is set then secret_token will be ignored.
    #api_key:

    # Secret token for the APM Server(s).
    #secret_token:


# ================================= Migration ==================================

# This allows to enable 6.7 migration aliases
#migration.6_to_7.enabled: true
```

i 've run

```
./filebeat -c filebeat.yml -e
```

This is the result

```
2021-09-20T09:55:05.324+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:665    Home path: [D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat] Config path: [D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat] Data path: [D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\data] Logs path: [D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\logs]
2021-09-20T09:55:05.327+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:673    Beat ID: 3957662b-f353-4de0-a6a7-3260cb6481ba
2021-09-20T09:55:05.375+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1014   Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat", "data": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat\\data", "home": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat", "logs": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat\\logs"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "3957662b-f353-4de0-a6a7-3260cb6481ba"}}}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.376+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1023   Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "703d589a09cfdbfd7f84c1d990b50b6b7f62ac29", "libbeat": "7.14.1", "time": "2021-08-26T09:12:57.000Z", "version": "7.14.1"}}}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.376+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1026   Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"windows","arch":"amd64","max_procs":12,"version":"go1.16.6"}}}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.403+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1030   Host info       {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2021-09-20T08:27:03.12+07:00","name":"nnhai2","ip":["fe80::6036:7939:ebe1:1d3e/64","192.168.82.42/23","fe80::984a:b076:b82f:bedf/64","169.254.190.223/16","fe80::d148:87f2:9bc8:8452/64","169.254.132.82/16","fe80::c4c:5978:a65:9c2a/64","169.254.156.42/16","fe80::488c:c4a3:51de:f987/64","169.254.249.135/16","fe80::e1fb:7ed2:192d:c665/64","169.254.198.101/16","::1/128","127.0.0.1/8","fe80::a42f:ed21:3139:b3a7/64","172.28.96.1/20"],"kernel_version":"10.0.19041.1237 (WinBuild.160101.0800)","mac":["70:b5:e8:5a:d1:0a","ac:82:47:8d:80:2e","ac:82:47:8d:80:2f","ae:82:47:8d:80:2e","00:09:0f:fe:00:01","ac:82:47:8d:80:32","00:15:5d:d4:9f:62"],"os":{"type":"windows","family":"windows","platform":"windows","name":"Windows 10 Pro","version":"10.0","major":10,"minor":0,"patch":0,"build":"19042.1237"},"timezone":"+07","timezone_offset_sec":25200,"id":"85952915-f150-4943-835a-55ae79b7bcb0"}}}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.404+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1059   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"cwd": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat", "exe": "D:\\AppData\\Elastic\\filebeat\\filebeat.exe", "name": "filebeat.exe", "pid": 15268, "ppid": 21388, "start_time": "2021-09-20T09:55:04.931+0700"}}}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.405+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:309    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.14.1
2021-09-20T09:55:05.405+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:184      Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'filebeat-7.14.1' as ILM is enabled.
2021-09-20T09:55:05.405+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-09-20T09:55:05.406+0700    INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: nnhai2
2021-09-20T09:55:05.410+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:473    filebeat start running.
2021-09-20T09:55:05.410+0700    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
2021-09-20T09:55:05.418+0700    INFO    memlog/store.go:119     Loading data file of 'D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\data\registry\filebeat' succeeded. Active transaction id=0
2021-09-20T09:55:05.418+0700    INFO    memlog/store.go:124     Finished loading transaction log file for 'D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\data\registry\filebeat'. Active transaction id=0
2021-09-20T09:55:05.420+0700    INFO    [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:109      States Loaded from registrar: 0
2021-09-20T09:55:05.420+0700    INFO    [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:71    Loading Inputs: 2
2021-09-20T09:55:05.420+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\logs]    {"input_id": "444806ec-503a-4a80-812f-a8c78e3f69a4"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.421+0700    INFO    [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:141   Starting input (ID: 1263043090716372778)
2021-09-20T09:55:05.456+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_deprecation.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_deprecation.json]    {"input_id": "aa771bd1-e31c-4061-bfe6-2897ff20dde4"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.456+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\gc.log.* c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\gc.log] {"input_id": "5c90cdc0-ca6b-4d51-a33c-3ce661ff324b"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.457+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_server.json]     {"input_id": "c7ba61e1-c4cb-42e6-8d9e-7acaa5c0d982"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.457+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_search_slowlog.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_indexing_slowlog.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_search_slowlog.json c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_indexing_slowlog.json]    {"input_id": "a83c170f-f55c-4de2-b6e3-969a3686c403"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.458+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_access.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_audit.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_audit.json]  {"input_id": "0696e6da-a676-4e5b-a550-0165db7b89af"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.472+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\MySQL\MySQL Server*\error.log*]       {"input_id": "cc0b720d-c796-47a2-87e7-7a3244fe8174"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.472+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\MySQL\MySQL Server*\mysql-slow.log*]  {"input_id": "2129affd-14ec-4468-8710-39eccfffb356"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.487+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\nginx\logs\*access.log*]      {"input_id": "44009138-8a88-4b07-8bd2-d04ab9d520bd"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.487+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\nginx\logs\error.log*]        {"input_id": "daa74eb0-538d-45fc-b657-13431186e186"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.488+0700    INFO    [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:108   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
2021-09-20T09:55:05.488+0700    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:164   Config reloader started
2021-09-20T09:55:05.498+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_server.json]     {"input_id": "77a9d5c1-6f98-414d-b368-dec4f7163ed2"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.499+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_search_slowlog.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_indexing_slowlog.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_search_slowlog.json c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_index_indexing_slowlog.json]    {"input_id": "beaa87b1-8ce8-4374-bee5-7372846a1968"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.500+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_access.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_audit.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_audit.json]  {"input_id": "b6c46042-3acf-440e-b788-3dfdaf789c10"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.500+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_deprecation.log c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\*_deprecation.json]    {"input_id": "d673b872-e9b2-496d-96b5-1e9792169b76"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.501+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\gc.log.* c:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs\gc.log] {"input_id": "5e4465a8-9ffb-42c6-ab6f-c9d269419ed4"}
2021-09-20T09:55:05.501+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-09-20T09:55:08.389+0700    INFO    [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go:101    add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type not detected.
2021-09-20T09:55:15.302+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.14.1
2021-09-20T09:55:15.454+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-gc-pipeline"}
2021-09-20T09:55:15.874+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-server-pipeline"}
2021-09-20T09:55:15.986+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-server-pipeline-plaintext"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.108+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-server-pipeline-json"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.227+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-slowlog-pipeline"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.335+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-slowlog-pipeline-plaintext"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.450+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-slowlog-pipeline-json"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.558+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-audit-pipeline"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.674+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-audit-pipeline-json"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.789+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-audit-pipeline-plaintext"}
2021-09-20T09:55:16.898+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-deprecation-pipeline"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.003+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-deprecation-pipeline-plaintext"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.111+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.14.1-elasticsearch-deprecation-pipeline-json"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.116+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\MySQL\MySQL Server*\error.log*]       {"input_id": "0043e24c-4f0f-487a-ab3e-2d2254e613ac"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.117+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\MySQL\MySQL Server*\mysql-slow.log*]  {"input_id": "eddd4b6e-3b7e-4cca-a0b0-e5422c6b7ccf"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.117+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-09-20T09:55:17.120+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.14.1
2021-09-20T09:55:17.137+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\nginx\logs\*access.log*]      {"input_id": "4af5fcde-53a7-4e67-9819-c153919b5f05"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.137+0700    INFO    [input] log/input.go:164        Configured paths: [c:\programdata\nginx\logs\error.log*]        {"input_id": "f4dafaa1-89cf-48d8-927e-eb292c5b186f"}
2021-09-20T09:55:17.137+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-09-20T09:55:17.141+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.14.1
2021-09-20T09:55:17.153+0700    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:224   Loading of config files completed.
2021-09-20T09:55:35.468+0700    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":78,"time":{"ms":93}},"total":{"ticks":390,"time":{"ms":405},"value":390},"user":{"ticks":312,"time":{"ms":312}}},"handles":{"open":306},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"f9fdf685-5d19-459c-a646-fceea8d53c4e","uptime":{"ms":30152},"version":"7.14.1"},"memstats":{"gc_next":19839152,"memory_alloc":12307216,"memory_sys":34381016,"memory_total":62482208,"rss":62062592},"runtime":{"goroutines":78}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":3,"starts":3},"reloads":1,"scans":1},"output":{"events":{"active":0},"type":"elasticsearch"},"pipeline":{"clients":10,"events":{"active":0},"queue":{"max_events":4096}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":12}}}}}       
2021-09-20T09:56:05.478+0700    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":109,"time":{"ms":32}},"total":{"ticks":421,"time":{"ms":32},"value":421},"user":{"ticks":312}},"handles":{"open":307},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"f9fdf685-5d19-459c-a646-fceea8d53c4e","uptime":{"ms":60164},"version":"7.14.1"},"memstats":{"gc_next":19839152,"memory_alloc":12714808,"memory_total":62889800,"rss":62160896},"runtime":{"goroutines":78}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":3}},"output":{"events":{"active":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":10,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}}}}}
2021-09-20T09:56:35.470+0700    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":140,"time":{"ms":46}},"total":{"ticks":452,"time":{"ms":46},"value":452},"user":{"ticks":312}},"handles":{"open":304},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"f9fdf685-5d19-459c-a646-fceea8d53c4e","uptime":{"ms":90157},"version":"7.14.1"},"memstats":{"gc_next":19839152,"memory_alloc":13110648,"memory_total":63285640,"rss":62164992},"runtime":{"goroutines":72}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":3}},"output":{"events":{"active":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":10,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}}}}}
```

but i have n't seen any data in kibana.

This is the result of GET _cat/indices?v

```
#! Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security.
health status index                             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .geoip_databases                  qeZJyRoKRlW7Xu7EE2ytcw   1   0         42            0     40.8mb         40.8mb
green  open   .apm-custom-link                  5aba-WkIS5yl-Eui7vpfcQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .kibana_task_manager_7.14.1_001   1zkRA6c6SXiMcqCtSyrSqQ   1   0         14          344      1.4mb          1.4mb
green  open   .apm-agent-configuration          dppb9LlKQLWTzYBiLZjViA   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
yellow open   filebeat-7.14.1-2021.09.19-000001 TpsVGELhRwC-_dxGH7nGKQ   1   1          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .async-search                     KZgq-leNT_qt_dM8TOUQ6A   1   0          0            0       231b           231b
green  open   .kibana_7.14.1_001                D4UISLPMQlGmCjNgGIrOTw   1   0       2251           11      2.7mb          2.7mb
green  open   .kibana-event-log-7.14.1-000001   cspR3zh9T1emwvNA131noQ   1   0          3            0     16.4kb         16.4kb
green  open   .tasks                            5dHd_BZpSVilDmVQy6kE7w   1   0          4            0     27.3kb         27.3kb
```

is it required specific structure log file or i can put any thing in there or where can i get sample log file to test the connection to put in my folder at D:\AppData\Elastic\filebeat\logs ?

Also, where can i find some best practice to config filebeat, i 've read the document at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html. But it is too simple, many things were not explained like how to config and test modules (we have dozens modules pensando, postgresql, proofpoint, rabbitmq,....)

Comment: what's the output from when you run it with the command?

Comment: @MarkWalkom i've included the result, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: it looks like it thinks the files have been read. what's the output from `_cat/indices?v`?

Comment: How do i get output from _cat/indices?v ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html, which you can do via curl or in Kibana Dev Tools

Comment: @MarkWalkom I've updated the result of GET _cat/indices?v. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237274/discussion-between-nguyn-ngc-hi-and-mark-walkom).

Comment: ok you've got the index there - `filebeat-7.14.1-2021.09.19-000001` - but nothing in it. can you try deleting the registry file and see if that processes the file?